# Help getting a BLDC motor with ESC working with my PS4 Controller

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, processing

I'm a hobbyist and have been working on building a small ROV. I want to be able to control several DC motors independently so I went down to my local hobby store and they helped me chose a DC motor, [Firma Spektrum 6000kv](https://www.spektrumrc.com/product/firma-brushless-motor-esc-2-in-1-combo-6000kv/SPMXSEM0501.html), and a battery, [Lectron Pro 7.4V 5200mAh](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00T3FTP54). One day I want to be able to control 4 of them but only bought 1 for now so I can test it and figure out my code. Im using an arduino uno, ran the standard firmata example in Arudino IDE and wrote the code below in processing IDE.

I want to use my PS4 controller for this, so I used the GameControllerPlus configurator to assign the buttons to my dc motor. I only have 1 of these servos so I set the on off to the Y axis of the left joystick on the PS4 controller (fbThrusterY). When I run my code I get a NullPointerException, I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it. I've run two, smaller dc motors while using a MOSFET on a breadboard. This worked with the code provided, I think the problem lies with the ESC. From reading online it sounds like I'm using an incorrect variable somewhere but cant figure out where.

```
import processing.serial.*;

import net.java.games.input.*;
import org.gamecontrolplus.*;
import org.gamecontrolplus.gui.*;

import cc.arduino.*;
import org.firmata.*;

ControlDevice cont;
ControlIO control;

Arduino arduino;

//int fbThrusterX = 50; // 0 - 255
int fbThrusterY = 0; 
float thumbY;
//float thumbX;

void setup() {
  //color box repersting range of motion of controller
   size(360, 200);
  
   control = ControlIO.getInstance(this);
   cont = control.getMatchedDevice("thrust");
   
   //if controller is not plugged in or connected
   //this error message will pop up and the program will stop 
   if (cont == null) {
     println("nope");
     System.exit(-1);
  }
  
  //println(Arduino.list());
  arduino = new Arduino(this, Arduino.list()[0], 57600);
  
  for(int i=0; i<= 50; i++)
    arduino.pinMode(i, Arduino.SERVO);
   
}

public void getUserInput(){
  //assign our float value
  //to access controller
  thumbY = map(cont.getSlider("fbThrusterY").getValue(), -1, 1, 0, 100);
  //thumbX = map(cont.getSlider("fbThrusterX").getValue(), -1, 1, 0, 100);
  //println(thumb);
   
}

void draw(){
  getUserInput();
  background(thumbY, 100, 255, 0);
  //background(thumbX, 0, 255, 100);
  
  arduino.analogWrite(3, (int)thumbY);
  //arduino.analogWrite(5, (int)thumbX);
}
```

Comment: Do you know [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384)?

Comment: (Setting pin 0 to 50 inclusive to `Arduino.SERVO` looks off.) Do you get any additional information with that `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Heres what I get when I run the code:

Comment: =======================================================
Failed to initialize device HIDI2C Device because of: java.io.IOException: Failed to acquire device (8007001e)
NullPointerException

Comment: (`8007001e` *should* be documented *somewhere* - only thing a superficial search offers is *Failed to acquire device* - meh.)

Comment: is it failing to acquire the arduino or the ESC? I tried changing the Arduino.list()[0] to "COM3" and got the same error, it took longer to load this time however.